# While database is offline, Flask app freezes untill SQLAlchemy connection timeout expires

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a **APScheduler** task set to run every 5 seconds, in the task the program will try to connect **MSSQL server** to run a query. The app has no issues when all connections are okey. But when I tried to run the program while my MSSQL server offline, the app freezes till the connection timeout expires. Like the other parts where viewing or getting results from a api routes stays halted till the timeout expires.

My scheduler task module:

```py
import pprint
import sys

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from pymongo import errors, UpdateOne

from app import list_machine_jobs

from .models import *
from .mongo_connection import PackJobCollection
from . import sql_db


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


def task_update_pack_jobs():
    """Task to update achieved production for all plans #runs every 30sec"""

    plans: dict[str, PackJob] = {}
    bulk_update_data = []
    plan_data = PackJobCollection.find({"status": {"$ne": PackJobStatus.CLOSED}})
    for item in plan_data:
        job = PackJob(**item)
        key = f"{job.product_code}x{job.packing.pack_code}"
        plans[key] = job

    if plans:
        # FIXME: App freezes till connection timeout expires if db offline
        res = sql_db.query_st_production(plans.values())
        if res:
            for prod_code, pack_code, achieved in res:
                job = plans.pop(f"{prod_code}x{pack_code}", None)
                if job and job.achieved != achieved:
                    new_value = {"achieved": achieved}
                    if achieved >= job.target_plan:
                        # and job.status != PackJobStatus.ON_HOLD
                        new_value["status"] = PackJobStatus.FINISHED
                    elif job.status in [PackJobStatus.PLANNED, PackJobStatus.FINISHED]:
                        new_value["status"] = PackJobStatus.RUNNING

                    bulk_update_data.append(
                        UpdateOne({"_id": job._id}, {"$set": new_value})
                    )

            # Rest of the plans that didn't recieved any updates from db
            for job in plans.values():
                if job.achieved != 0:
                    bulk_update_data.append(
                        UpdateOne(
                            {"_id": job._id},
                            {"$set": {"achieved": 0, "status": PackJobStatus.PLANNED}},
                        )
                    )
            if bulk_update_data:
                try:
                    result = PackJobCollection.bulk_write(bulk_update_data)
                    print(result)
                except errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
                    pprint(bwe.details)
                except:
                    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                    print("Bulk Write to MongoDB failed \n{}".format(e))

    # Send new packet data through websocket
    list_machine_jobs()
    # print(f"task completed @ {datetime.datetime.now()}")


scheduler.add_job(
    task_update_pack_jobs,
    "interval",
    id="pack_job_updates",
    seconds=5,
    max_instances=1,
    misfire_grace_time=60,
)
```

The MSSQL database I am trying to connect is build by another application, I don't want to damage the application even by accidentally modifying the database. So connecting separately through **SQLAlchemy**.

My SQL query module:

```py
import os

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

from core.models import PackJob

from .mssql_models import *


ST_DB_CONN_STR = (
    r"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    rf'Server={os.environ.get("ST_DB_HOST")};'
    rf'Database={os.environ.get("ST_DB_NAME")};'
    rf'uid={os.environ.get("ST_DB_USER")};'
    rf'pwd={os.environ.get("ST_DB_PASS")};'
    r"Integrated Security=false;"
)


st_conn_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": ST_DB_CONN_STR})

engine = sa.create_engine(st_conn_url, connect_args={"timeout": 3})

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def query_st_production(jobs: list[PackJob]) -> list[tuple[int, int, int]]:
    """Fetch production w.r.t time

    :returns: list[tuple[product_code, pack_code, production]]

    """

    result = None
    cond = []
    for job in jobs:
        cond.append(
            sa.and_(
                *[
                    StStorageScan.store_date >= job.start_date,
                    StStorageScan.store_date < job.end_date,
                    StPacking.product_code == job.product_code,
                    StPacking.pack_code == job.packing.pack_code,
                ]
            )
        )
    if len(cond) > 1:
        cond = [sa.or_(*cond)]  # Multiple items to lookup

    try:
        # FIXME: Makes the app stuck till connection timeout expires.
        with Session() as s:
            result = (
                s.query(
                    StPacking.product_code,
                    StPacking.pack_code,
                    sa.func.count(StStorageScan.mc_code),
                )
                .select_from(StStorageScan)
                .join(StPacking, StPacking.mc_code == StStorageScan.mc_code)
                .filter(*cond)
                .group_by(StPacking.product_code, StPacking.pack_code)
                .all()
            )
    except sa.exc.OperationalError:
        # SQL Server unreachable
        pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[MSSQL] Failed due to:\n {e}")

    return result
```

My App behavior [connection timeout=3sec, task run every 5 sec]:

[image: App route freeze demo]

What I tried so far:

- Tried with both `APScheduler` and `Flask-APScheduler`, both has no effect on this behavior
- Tried with separate python `threading` no effect
- Reduced connection timeout to 1 second: the freeze timing became nearly 1 second.
- Same issue in plain flask debug, socketio-eventlet, gunicorn-eventlet
- `time.sleep(30)` inside the task doesn't have any issue, that works in separate thread. So that doesn't freezes the app.

Conclusion I came up with:
Issue has something to do with the driver or with the connection setup in SQLAlchemy or my server setup (#in docker).

For ref: [my repository](https://github.com/kalaLokia/fbr_om_display/tree/dev)

Comment: Did you try `threaded=True` on the Flask app?

Comment: Just tried now. No effect. Also tried applying the same on SocketIO as well. And one somewhere described like `async_io='threading'` also tried with no effect

Comment: It is also okey to if I `time.sleep(30)` in my task, that doesn't affect program. Only the `Session()` call makes it halt